# Reading matrix from file takes too much RAM

Tags: matrix, io, julia

I am reading a matrix from a file using `readdlm`. The file is about 400 MB in size. My PC has 8 GB of RAM. When I try to `readdlm` the matrix from this file, my PC eventually freezes, while the RAM consumption goes up until it consumes everything. The matrix is simply a 0, 1 matrix.

I don't understand why this happens. Storing this matrix in memory shouldn't take more than the 400 MB necessary to store the file.

What can I do?

The code I am using is simple:

```
readdlm("data.txt")
```

where `data.txt` is a 400mb text file of tab-separated values. I am on Linux Mint 17.3, Julia 0.4.

Comment: What's the call you're making? what type are you using?

Comment: What is your OS. By default readdlm doesn't use mmap on Windows.

Comment: It's almost impossible to get a good answers to coding questions without giving example code to show what you're doing.